# Does necessitarianism imply that every true statement about the physical world is a law of physics?

Tags: reference-request, philosophy-of-physics, necessity

I am someone who believes that nothing is possible except the actual. In my view, all non-actual possible statements are false. So, for example, the statements "Unicorns could have evolved on Earth" and "Someone besides Einstein could have come up with the theory of Relativity" are both false, at least in my view. I believe this view is called necessitarianism. I have noticed an interesting implication of this view. This view, in my mind, implies that all true statements about the physical world are laws of physics. Even a statement like, "There is a phone on my desk", would be a law of physics, since it could not be otherwise. Perhaps I could just bite the bullet, and admit that strictly speaking, all true statements about the physical world are laws of physics. But I wonder if there is another option. My real question is, has any philosopher found a way to define laws of physics such that even a necessitarianist can admit that not all true statements about the physical world are laws of physics? I would very much like such a definition, because I do not want to have to admit that all facts about the physical world are laws of physics.

Comment: Why does it matter if they're all laws of physics, if everything is necessary? And isn't everything that happens an instance of laws anyway? (We forego laws with fail rates/exceptions, now, I suppose.)